# How do I use Distance Matrix API in ReactJS using @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, google-distancematrix-api, react-google-maps

I am using the above package and I can't find proper documentation to implement the code. Currently, this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, DistanceMatrixService } from "@react-google-maps/api";
class ExampleDirections extends Component {
  state = {
    response: null,
    travelMode: "DRIVING",
    origin: "",
    destination: "",
  };

  distanceCallback = (response) => {
    console.log("Hello");
    console.log(response);

    if (response !== null) {
      if (response.status === "OK") {
        this.setState(() => ({
          response,
        }));
      } else {
        console.log("response: ", response);
      }
    }
  };

  checkDriving = ({ target: { checked } }) => {
    checked &&
      this.setState(() => ({
        travelMode: "DRIVING",
      }));
  };

  getOrigin = (ref) => {
    this.origin = ref;
  };

  getDestination = (ref) => {
    this.destination = ref;
  };

  onClick = () => {
    if (this.origin.value !== "" && this.destination.value !== "") {
      this.setState(() => ({
        origin: this.origin.value,
        destination: this.destination.value,
      }));
    }
  };

  onMapClick = (...args) => {
    console.log("onClick args: ", args);
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="map">
      <div className="map-settings">
        <hr className="mt-0 mb-3" />

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="ORIGIN">Origin</label>
              <br />
              <input
                id="ORIGIN"
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                ref={this.getOrigin}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="DESTINATION">Destination</label>
              <br />
              <input
                id="DESTINATION"
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                ref={this.getDestination}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div className="form-group custom-control custom-radio mr-4">
            <input
              id="DRIVING"
              className="custom-control-input"
              name="travelMode"
              type="radio"
              checked={this.state.travelMode === "DRIVING"}
              onChange={this.checkDriving}
            />
            <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="DRIVING">
              Driving
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          type="button"
          onClick={this.onClick}
        >
          Build Route
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="map-container">
        <GoogleMap
          id="map"
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          zoom={14}
          center={center}
          options={options}
        >
          <DistanceMatrixService
            options={{
              destinations: this.state.destination,
              origins: this.state.origin,
              travelMode: this.state.travelMode,
            }}
            callback={this.distanceCallback}
          />
          )}
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExampleDirections;
```

Am getting the following error with this code:

**InvalidValueError: in property origins: not an Array**

I want to use all the other services like directions, places, autocomplete together later. Now am trying to work things individually and I am having a problem only with this.

Better alternatives to the package are also fine. THANK YOU

**CONTINUED**

So I got my problem solved with the answer from below. But, now when I try to save the response in a state, the API is called endlessly. Down below is my code. THanks for the help.

```
<DistanceMatrixService
            options={{
              destinations: [{ lat: 1.296788, lng: 103.778961 }],
              origins: [{ lng: 72.89216, lat: 19.12092 }],
              travelMode: "DRIVING",
            }}
            callback={(res) => {
              console.log("RESPONSE", res);
              this.setState({
                totalTime: res.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text,
                totalDistance: res.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text,
              });
            }}
          />
```

It works fine when I only call console.log or when I declare variables and save values in them. But, when I try using setState, this issue occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having a hard time figuring out the revamped react-google-maps as well.I got the distance matrix working as follows:

```
<DistanceMatrixService
 options={{
           destinations: [{lat:1.296788, lng:103.778961}],
           origins: [{lng:103.780267, lat:1.291692}],
           travelMode: "DRIVING",
         }}
 callback = {(response) => {console.log(response)}}
/>
```

Ensure your destinations and origins are arrays and don't forget to enable all the necessary APIs.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. So i got it working. It gives me a response but how do i extract the time to travel and the distance in between the points from the "response".

Comment: Great! response.rows[0].elements will give you an array of the same size as your destinations array. You can then access travel time and distance using response.rows[0].elements[index].distance.text and response.rows[0].elements[index].duration.text.

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot. You have helped me a ton. Looks easy now after you helped me out with this.

Comment: Hey man I ran into another issue. Would be glad if you could help me sort it out. THanks

Comment: Hey, the way I did it was to add a simple boolean state variable to restrict the number of API calls. For example, you can have a state called control set to true first. I use it this way as I only need to make the call once. If you need to make more calls, you can play around with the state of control to prevent unnecessary calls.

Comment: Example:
```
{control && (<DistanceMatrixService
            options={{
              destinations: [{ lat: 1.296788, lng: 103.778961 }],
              origins: [{ lng: 72.89216, lat: 19.12092 }],
              travelMode: "DRIVING",
            }}
            callback={(res) => {
              console.log("RESPONSE", res);
              this.setState({
                control : false,
                totalTime: res.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text,
                totalDistance: res.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text,
              });
            }}
          />)}
```

Comment: Ah man u a hero. Thanks again. Trying to build this Uber like ambulance service for my college project. Your help made me go on. Thanks.